# Making pie charts using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am using MySQL and PHP as backend.
Is there an example to illustrate the use of d3.js with php and MySQL.

Comment: Follow the instructions here: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/using-mysql-database-as-source-of-data.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I draw pie chart for static data . You can extract script in .js file and use dynamic data.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Pie chart
    </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src='d3.v3.min.js' charset='utf-8' ></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var metadata = {
                'x' : 'name' ,
                'y' : 'percent' };

            var data = [
                {label : 'name1', value : 25},
                {label : 'name2', value : 20},
                {label : 'name3', value : 40},
                {label : 'name4', value : 15} ];

            var width = 1100 , height = 650 , radius = 250 ,
            color = ["#C5AAF5","#FB7374","#A3CBF1","#79BFA1","#F5A352","#94B3C8", "#F9D08B","#B2AC4E","#64BD4F","#C09372"];

            var colorDescriptions = [];

            var svgContainer = d3.select("body") // create svg container
                .append("svg:svg")
                .data([data])
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .append("svg:g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + 300 + "," + 300 + ")") ;;

            var arc = d3.svg.arc() // draw arc of given radius
                .outerRadius(radius);

            var pie = d3.layout.pie() // assign data for pie chart
                .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

            var arcs = svgContainer.selectAll("g.slice") // slice the circle
                .data(pie)   
                .enter()
                .append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "slice");

            arcs.append("svg:path") // fill color in each slice
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) { 
                var colorSelected =  color[i];
                colorDescriptions.push({"colorSelected": colorSelected, "label": data[i].label});
                return colorSelected; } )
                .attr("d", arc)

            arcs.append("svg:text") // write slice information values
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                d.innerRadius = 0;
                d.outerRadius = radius;
                    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
                })
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(function(d, i) { return data[i].value; })
                .style("font-family","monospace")
                .style("fill", "#3f3f3f")
                .style("font-size", "20px");

            descriptionText = "Pie Chart of " + metadata.x + " with " + metadata.y; // pie chart description

            var description = svgContainer.append("g").attr("class", "description"); // pie chart description
            var desc_label = description.append("text")
                .attr("class", "description")
                .attr("y", 300)
                .attr("x", 000)
                .text(descriptionText)
                .style("font-weight", "bold")
                .style("font-size", "20px")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle"); 

            var pieChartLabels = svgContainer.append("g").attr("id","pie-chart-labels");   //index for pie chart : name
            pieChartLabels.selectAll("text").data(colorDescriptions).enter().append("svg:text")
                .text(function(d) { return d.label; } ).attr("x",440)
                .attr("y",function(d, i) { return 14 + i*30; })
                .style("font-size", "20px");

            var pieChartLabelsColors = svgContainer.append("g").attr("id","pie-chart-labels-colors"); 
            pieChartLabelsColors.selectAll("rect").data(colorDescriptions).enter().append("rect") 
                .attr("x",400)
                .attr("y",function(d, i) { return i*30; })
                .attr("width", 25)
                .attr("height", 15)
                .style("fill" , function(d) { return d.colorSelected; }); //index for pie chart : color
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```